# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

Tags: vb.net

Estou tendo um problema no return **"Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types"**, como proceder?

```
        Public Function RetornaValorTotalPremiacao(ByVal strCodigoProposta As String) As Decimal
        Try
            Dim objApoioConexao As New ApoioConexao

            objApoioConexao.AdicionaParametro(strCodigoProposta, "@CD_PROP")

            Return Convert.ToDecimal(objDMConexao.ExecutaComando(My.Settings.ConexaoAtiva, "[dbo].[usp_sel_valor_total_premiacao]", CommandType.StoredProcedure, objApoioConexao.RetornaArrayParametros))

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Dentro do código

```
bjDMConexao.ExecutaComando(My.Settings.ConexaoAtiva, "[dbo].[usp_sel_valor_total_premiacao]", CommandType.StoredProcedure, objApoioConexao.RetornaArrayParametros)
```

O valor retornado é DBNull, e você está tentando dar um cast para Decimal, faça  uma verificação antes de tentar dar um cast para decimal.

Comment: Resolvido ISNULL(SUM(PRO.VALOR_CUSTA),0)!

Comment: Coloca como resposta para ajudar os próximos humanos com o mesmo problema.